# JPA Query in inheritance tables

Tags: java, jpa, inheritance, jpql

i'm new on JPA, i need some help with a query that i would like to make.

This are my entities:

**Service Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "service", schema = "db2")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "serviceType")
public abstract class Service implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idService;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "pack-serv", schema = "db2", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idService"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idPackage"))
    private List<Package> packages;

    public Service() {
    }
    //getter and setter of all attributes
}
```

**Fixed Internet entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "service", schema = "db2")
@DiscriminatorValue("Fixed Internet")
public class FixedInternet extends Service implements Serializable  {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private int GB;
    private int feeExtraGB;
    @Column(name="serviceType", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    protected String type;
    
    public FixedInternet() {
        super();
    }
     //getter and setter of all attributes
}
```

I would like to retrieve all FixedInternet services that are related to a specific package ID. I made this query:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "FixedInternet.findServicesByPackID", query = "SELECT s.GB, s.feeExtraGB, s.idService FROM FixedInternet s JOIN s.packages p WHERE p.idPackage = ?1 AND s.type LIKE 'Fixed Internet'")
```

but when i run it an error shows up related to SQL syntax:

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-serv t2, db2.package t1 WHERE ((((t1.IDPACKAGE = 1) AND t0.serviceType LIKE 'Fi' at line 1
Error Code: 1064
Call: SELECT t0.GB, t0.FEEEXTRAGB, t0.IDSERVICE FROM db2.service t0, db2.pack-serv t2, db2.package t1 WHERE ((((t1.IDPACKAGE = ?) AND t0.serviceType LIKE ?) AND (t0.serviceType = ?)) AND ((t2.idService = t0.IDSERVICE) AND (t1.IDPACKAGE = t2.idPackage)))
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
```

I can't resolve it, someone can help me to understand what i'm wrong?

This is the ER Diagram of the database if it could help: [ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEnVa.png)

**UPDATE**: without the part of "s.type LIKE 'Fixed Internet'", the error is pretty the same:

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-serv t2, db2.package t1 WHERE ((((t1.IDPACKAGE = 1) AND t0.serviceType LIKE 'Fi' at line 1
Error Code: 1064
Call: SELECT t0.GB, t0.FEEEXTRAGB, t0.IDSERVICE FROM db2.service t0, db2.pack-serv t2, db2.package t1 WHERE (((t1.IDPACKAGE = ?) AND (t0.serviceType = ?)) AND ((t2.idService = t0.IDSERVICE) AND (t1.IDPACKAGE = t2.idPackage)))
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
```

Comment: please add all the relevant code to the `@NamedQuery` . The error seems to not match what you have posted

Comment: Why are you adding "AND s.type LIKE 'Fixed Internet'" to your query? Querying on FixedInternet automatically adds filters so you only get back FixedInternet instances. This would only be necessary if you want to exclude potential FixedInternet subclasses from the results, and you should be using the JPQL 'TYPE' expression for that "where TYPE(s) = FixedInternet"

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos the query is the one that i wrote, it is completed, there is nothing else..

Comment: @Chris i also tried to not add "AND s.type LIKE 'Fixed Internet', but the error is pretty much the same (i updated the question with the result without that part)

Comment: the error doesn't match the query being executed - there are too many parentheses and the error states Like is being used instead of '='. Looks too much like your old query, like the statement was cached and being reused - did you maybe cut and paste the old error string? Otherwise, try a clean restart, and maybe turn on SQL and parameter logging to see the statement that is executed before it issues the error. It is odd it starts off with the '-' though. Is that character allowed in table names for your database? You might try changing the table name to avoid '-', using '_' instead.

Comment: @Chris i confirm that this is the error, no cut and paste.. I know there are too many parameters and this is the reason why i don't understand how can i fix it.. How can I turn on SQL and parameter logging to see the statement that is executed? 
For the '-', my tables don't have that name, i don't know why it is in the error.. you can see tables in the ER Diagram that is linked

Comment: JoinTable(name = "pack-serv") is defined in your entity, so it is one of the tables. Try something different, or try escaping the table name so it is JoinTable(name = "\"PACK-SERV\"") and see if that helps. As for SQL logging - that depends on your JPA provider. Check their docs. As for the error not changing - restart your app and show the full exception stack with the new query, as I can't see anything anymore that explains that error message. What DB and JDBC driver versions are you using?

Comment: @Chris thank you, it worked! Sorry for the delay in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error when I tried to CREATE a Table.

Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER (ID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, DATE DATE, ORDERTYPE INTEGER, VERSION ' at line 1

Error Code: 1064

Call: CREATE TABLE ORDER (ID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, DATE DATE, ORDERTYPE INTEGER, VERSION INTEGER, CUSTOMER_ID BIGINT, PRIMARY KEY (ID))

The problem was that I was using a word reserved for MySQL (ORDER) to name the Table. The solution was to change the Table name to other.

If this helps...